# How to Open a file in ASP

Tags: file-io, asp-classic

I don't know how to open a file in ASP.  Here is my code which is not working.

```
<%
    Dim vid_file
    vid_file = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")& "cannon\pay\vid.dat"
    Dim vkey_file
    vkey_file = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")& "cannon\pay\vkey.dat"

    dim fp1,f
    set fp1 = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set f=fp1.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("vid_file"),8,true)
    f.WriteLine("This text will be added to the end of file")
    f.Close

    set f=Nothing
    set fp1=Nothing

    'Single Variable Declarations
    dim fp2,f2
    set fp2 = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'fExists=FileSysObj.FileExists(vid_file)
    set f2=fp2.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("vkey_file"),8,true)
    'set TextStreamObj = fp2.OpenTextFile(vkey_file,1,true) 
    'TextStreamObj.WriteLine("This text will be added to the end of file")
    f2.WriteLine("This text will be added to the end of file")
    f2.Close

    set f2=Nothing
    set fp2=Nothing
%>
```

Comment: **How** is it not working?  Are there any error messages?

Comment: @Cheran S :) can u plz check this weather i m wrong or right ? http://pastebin.com/5Wqd6kk2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%
    Dim vid_file
    vid_file = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")& "cannon\pay\vid.dat"
    Dim vkey_file
    vkey_file = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")& "cannon\pay\vkey.dat"

    dim fp1,f
    set fp1 = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     set f=fp1.OpenTextFile(vid_file,8,true)
    f.WriteLine("This text will be added to the end of file")
    f.Close
    set f=Nothing
    set fp1=Nothing
    'Single Variable Declarations
    dim fp2,f2
    set fp2 = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'fExists=FileSysObj.FileExists(vid_file)
    set f2=fp2.OpenTextFile(vkey_file,8,true)
    'set TextStreamObj = fp2.OpenTextFile(vkey_file,1,true) 
    'TextStreamObj.WriteLine("This text will be added to the end of file")
    f2.WriteLine("This text will be added to the end of file")
    f2.Close
    set f2=Nothing
    set fp2=Nothing
    %>
```

Comment: You just need to replace this code Server.MapPath("vkey_file") to vkey_file , That's it... It will work perfectly.

Comment: I have edited my Answer, I have tested with HTML File which is working for me and writing "This text will be added to the end of file" in test.html page.

Comment: @ Jinesh Jain:)ok I have 10-12 lines in PHP can You please convert them in to ASP ? please because i don't no ASP

Comment: Yes sure please write down I will try to convert this in Asp.

Comment: from 1 to line 5 i solved as this question now, from line 8 to 23 i have to solve .... ??

Comment: Sure,I will look in to this and will reply you.

Comment: :) Okk i am wating and if u have asked any question regarding this u can ask me ..!!

Comment: :) I am also trying at the same time

Comment: Hi, Right Now I am busy so I will try conversion by tomorrow.

Comment: :) dude actually its urgent otherwise i wil do that

Comment: :) can u plz check my this code http://pastebin.com/5Wqd6kk2 right now if else is not working

Comment: :) right now i m doing this   If Not f AND Not f2 Then
 'if(!f || !f2) but it gives an error Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: try  If (NOT IsObject(f) OR NOT IsObject(f2) ) Then  insted of If NOT f OR NOT f2 Then

Comment: If (NOT IsObject(f) OR NOT IsObject(f2)) Then i am trying this now works but new error in  vid = Trim(f.ReadLine)